# PHP Calculating Time Difference in Hours Between Two Timezones

Tags: php, date, time, timezone, timezone-offset

I need to work out the difference in hours between two timezones and I am running into some issues when the timezone that is ahead moves to the next day.

Example:

```
//Let's say it is 11pm 23:00 in LA
$local_tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$local = new DateTime('now', $local_tz);
$local_hour = $local->format('H');

//NY is 3 hours ahead, so it is 2am, 02:00
$user_tz = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$user = new DateTime('now', $user_tz);
$user_hour = $user->format('H');
```

Following the example in this question ([Calculate hours between dates in different time zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562526/calculate-hours-between-dates-in-different-time-zones)) I get an incorrect result:

```
$diff = $user_tz->getOffset($local);
error_log('$diff '.gmdate("H:i:s", $diff)); //outputs 20:00:00
```

If it was 4pm in LA, therefore 7pm in NY then it is easy:

```
$time_diff = ($user_h - $local_h); //$time_diff = 3;
```

But when NY moves to the next day I again get incorrect results:

```
$time_diff = ($user_h - $local_h); //$time_diff = -21;
```

So how can I account for another timezone which has moved to a new day?

Comment: `$time_diff = $time_diff > 0 ? $time_diff : $time_diff + 24;` Maybe this will fix it ?

Answer (score 19):

You can get difference in hours between two time zones using timezone offset try below code:

```
$local_tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$local = new DateTime('now', $local_tz);

//NY is 3 hours ahead, so it is 2am, 02:00
$user_tz = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$user = new DateTime('now', $user_tz);

$local_offset = $local->getOffset() / 3600;
$user_offset = $user->getOffset() / 3600;

$diff = $user_offset - $local_offset;
print_r($diff); //outputs 3
```

Comment: you are a rockstar :)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a solution to this, the DateInterval class kept throwing out 21 for me aswell, although when I outputted the object I could see the hour as 3.

Since DateTime does the comparison with epoch and ignores timezone, I had to create a new DateTime for both times and THEN run the comparison.

```
//Let's say it is 11pm 23:00 in LA
$local_tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$local = new DateTime('now', $local_tz);

//NY is 3 hours ahead, so it is 2am, 02:00
$user_tz = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$user = new DateTime('now', $user_tz);

$usersTime = new DateTime($user->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$localsTime = new DateTime($local->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$interval = $usersTime->diff($localsTime);
print_r($interval->h); //outputs 3
```

Running tests with `$user->modify("-4 hours"); $local->modify("-4 hours");` returns 3. (which puts one of those just before midnight the previous day)

Comment: Note: Not all time zones are in full hours. This will output "4" for 'America/Los_Angeles' and 'America/St_Johns', but they are 4.5 hours different.

`$interval->h + ((float)$interval->i / 60)` would do the trick

Answer (score -1):

Function to calculate the difference in hours among two timezones, (input should be in "+00:00" format).

```
function timezoneDifferenceInHours( $timezone_1, $timezone_2){
    //get hour value of first timezone
    $a = explode(":",$timezone_1)[0];
    //get hour value of second timezone
    $b = explode(":",$timezone_2)[0];
    //calculate difference
    $difference =0;
    if($a < $b)
        $difference = $b-$a;
    else
        $difference = $a-$b;
    return $diffsec;
}
```

Function call : (returns difference among timezones in hours)

```
echo timezoneDifferenceInHours( "-07:00", "+05:30" );

//Output : 12
```